# Null Pointer Exception in Text Game

Tags: java

I am making a simple text adventure game. I have a room class and an item class.

Each room has multiple items, and I am trying to make a method called addItem to store theitems in an ArrayList, but I get a NullPointerException when I try to add an item.

Room class

```
public class Room
{
    private String description;
    private HashMap<String, Room> exits;
    private ArrayList<Item>items;

    /**
     * Create a room described "description". Initially, it has
     * no exits. "description" is something like "a kitchen" or
     * "an open court yard".
     * @param description The room's description.
     */
    public Room(String description) 
    {
        this.description=description;
        exits = new HashMap<String, Room>();
        items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    }

    /**
     * Define an exit from this room.
     * @param direction The direction of the exit.
     * @param neighbor  The room to which the exit leads.
     */
    public void setExit(String direction, Room neighbor) 
    {
        exits.put(direction, neighbor);
    }

    /**
     * @return The short description of the room
     * (the one that was defined in the constructor).
     */
    public String getShortDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     * Return a description of the room in the form:
     *     You are in the kitchen.
     *     Exits: north west
     * @return A long description of this room
     */
    public String getLongDescription()
    {
        return "You are " + description + ".\n" + getExitString();
    }

    /**
     * Return a string describing the room's exits, for example
     * "Exits: north west".
     * @return Details of the room's exits.
     */
    private String getExitString()
    {
        String returnString = "Exits:";
        Set<String> keys = exits.keySet();
        for(String exit : keys) {
            returnString += " " + exit;
        }
        return returnString;
    }

    /**
     * Return the room that is reached if we go from this room in direction
     * "direction". If there is no room in that direction, return null.
     * @param direction The exit's direction.
     * @return The room in the given direction.
     */
    public Room getExit(String direction) 
    {
        return exits.get(direction);
    }
    /**
     * adds new item to the room
     */
    public void addItem(String description)
    {
        Item Iitem = new Item(description);
        items.add(Iitem);
    }
}
```

Item Class

```
public class Item
{
   private String description; 

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Item
     */
    public Item(String description)
    {
        this.description=description;
    }
    /**
     * gets description of the item
     */
    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }

}
```

Comment: where are you getting exception ?? please post the exception trace

Comment: On a side note. Do you really want `Item` to extend `Room`? I mean, with your current code, every `Item` has a `getExit` method... as well as `setExit`, `addItem`, etc.

Comment: -1 for indicating the failing line.

Comment: yeah.. i figured that it doesnt have to extend.. its all ok

Comment: without the "extend" you cannot call "super"... And by the way, is your question answered? If yes, please accept an answer by clicking the hollow check mark :)

Comment: yeah.. i fixed it.. will update the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never initialized `items`, so it's `null`.

```
items = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

Also I suggest you use interface for declaration, instead of a specific implementation

```
private Map<String, Room> exits;        // stores exits of this room.
private List<Item> items;
```

Comment: oh yeah :) my bad.. i knew i was missing something obvious

Comment: Usually the stacktrace of the exception gives you all the information you need to fix it. I suggest you learn to read them ;)

Comment: http://fr33kk0mpu73r.blogspot.com.es/2013/11/reading-java-exception-stacktraces.html

Comment: @user3401005: I just downloaded BlueJ and tried to instantiate your class and call a method, and when I do so a "Terminal window" opens where the lower part (error console) shows in red the stack trace and it can be copied there and also individual lines can be clicked to open the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialize the `ArrayList<Item> items`

You need to do:

```
ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

Comment: @m0skit0 Are You sure?

Comment: 100% sure. You can try and see.

Comment: @m0skit0 Well, it didn't, and whatever.

Comment: Lool your comment was after my edit, so i asked you that are you sure, then you insisted that it throw a warring.